# Is 'Can IDE X be used to develop ...?' like question on topic?

Tags: discussion, questions

I just saw two questions being asked about using Xcode to develop android applications, but [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515360) is closed while the [other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582802) remains open currently.

I know here may ask some questions about IDE related to programming, but not sure if this type of questions are on topic.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34320110/4354477) is about almost the same but regarding VS and robotics.

Comment: I can't see how these would be inherently off-topic, but they are prone to being broad - unless they happen to be answerable with a straight-up yes or no.

Comment: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/7274/31260)

Comment: That's pretty sad Q+A.  But who is going to post the this-question-has-no-clothes answer: "yes, of course you can turn your IDE into a text editor."  SO users only like happy answers.   Closing it only guarantees that nobody *can* post such an answer.

Comment: "Can X be used to do Y?" is almost invariably followed up by "How can X be used to do Y?" which can be answerable (if sufficiently narrowed down).

Comment: @mason: Conversely, when someone starts with "How can...", the answer is sometimes "It can't."

Comment: @Michael The answer is almost never "it can't". There's almost always a workaround, or it can be done with sufficient effort. The former is usually answerable. The latter may be too broad of a question to answer for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I don't get these kind of questions. Yes of course X can be used to develop Y, that still doesn't mean that *you* can do it. Lets work on that primarily and not worry about what tools can and cannot do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Questions about IDEs are generally on-topic, but that doesn't allow them to escape the rule of having to be about a specific, hopefully reproducible, issue. "Can X be used to do Y" is an overly broad question, regardless of the topic, and should probably be closed as such.

Comment: `"Can X be used to do Y" is an overly broad question`
How is that broad using the definition of "too broad" under the close flag? The answer is usually 'yes' or 'no' and does not lead to long discussion or long answers.

Comment: Can Aptana be used to develop for PHP? Yes. That's not broad at all. Is Aptana the right program to use for PHP? Now, that is a broad question. It depends on how the question is asked.

Comment: @ArtB: I guess the main problem is that the answer is almost always "Yes", but that "Yes" is almost always not what the asker wants. E.g. "Can Ruby be used for the `<script>` element in HTML". The answer is, of course, "Yes". The HTML specification does not say what languages are allowed there, and the element has a `type` attribute for exactly that reason. However, *implied* in that "Yes" is "… provided that you write a Ruby interpreter that can be embedded into a browser and then convince every major browser vendor to integrate your interpreter and wait a couple of years."

Comment: "Can Visual Studio be used to make Skynet?"

Comment: @JörgWMittag Excellent point, but some "How can I.." questions do not require what I like to call "Unreasonable Effort". For example: "How can I write TypeScript in the `<script>` element in HTML?" has a decent workaround that can be describe well enough in an answer.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I think you provided your own counter-example: that is an objective and useful answer (albeit I'd replace `convince every major browser vendor to integrate your interpreter and wait a couple of years` with `but there is no support in the wild for it`) and I'd upvote that. It is neither long nor going to spawn a conversation.

Answer (score 2):

The [answer to the second question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2584350/434551) is a rather poor answer.

1. It has a link to an external web site that supposedly contains the full answer.
2. The answer does not provide any more details that provide more insight.

Hence, it qualifies as a link only answer, and should be deleted.

The question itself has two close votes but apparently not enough users that follow the relevant tags thought the question deserves to be closed.

The core question in that post is:

> Has anyone setup the Android NDK & SDK to work with Xcode?

How can one answer such a question?

1. Yes, I have.
2. Yes, I have and here are the steps.
3. No, it can'be done.
4. No, it can't be done. This is what I tried and hence my conclusion.

If an answerer could have come up with an answer that is (2) or (4) above, it would be useful to a wider audience. As it stands now, that is not the case.

I would vote to close the question and delete the answer.

As a general guideline, such questions are not useful at all.